# Alignment of grid items in Material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

I'm working on a prototype to migrate a JavaFx window to a a web application using React.js & Material Ui. The result must be as close as possible of the look&feel of the JavaFx application.

The layout of the windows was pretty basic, it looks like a form with multiple text fields to read or input data.

I've 2 main questions as I'm having some difficulties to match with the expected layout. I'm using Material Ui and some grid components.

- First of all, how can I align the 3 left inputs fields (associated to AAAAAAA, FFF/FFF, HHHH so that the left borders of each input field are vertically aligned?
- Then, I'm missing something in the Grid usage. I don't get why, on the 3rd line, there is a blank space between the first input field and IIII. I'm looking for a way to remove this blanck space, i thought the grid would only occupy the required space by the label & the input fields, but apparently some other blank spaces are added. I added the blue, yellow and orange background colors to have a better sight of what's happening. I was expecting the "yellow" block to end at the end of the "orange" block.

Below you can find a screenshot of my result and the associated code
Thanks for your help!

[image]

```
<Grid container direction={'column'} spacing={1}>
    <Grid container item style={{width:"850px"}} >
        <Grid container item xs={3} spacing={1}>
            <Grid item>AAAAAAA</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={7}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 7, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid justify='flex-end' container item xs={8} spacing={1} >
            <Grid item>BBBB</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        
            <Grid item>CCCC</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>DDDD</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>EEEE/E</Grid>
            <Grid item item xs={2}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 4, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>/</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item style={{width:"850px"}}>
        <Grid container item xs={6} spacing={1}>
            <Grid item>FFF/FFF</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={9}>
                <Input 
                    fullWidth="true"
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 21, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={6} spacing={1}>
            <Grid item>GGGG</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={10}>
                <Input 
                    fullWidth="true"
                    inputProps={{maxLength: 21, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item style={{border:"1px solid red", width:"1000px"}}>
        <Grid container style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}spacing={1} xs={2}>
            <Grid item style={{backgroundColor: "blue"}}>HHHH</Grid>
            <Grid item style={{backgroundColor: "orange"}}>
                <Input 
                    fullWidth="true"
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 4, size: 4, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={1} xs={2}>
            <Grid item>IIII</Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <Input 
                    fullWidth="true"
                    inputProps={{maxLength: 4, size: 4, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to center the items vertically, you should use the prop `alignItems` and give it the value `center`. For the second problem, I can't help you without any reproduction of the problem:

```
  <Grid container direction={'column'} spacing={1}>
    <Grid container item style={{width:"850px"}} >
        <Grid container item xs={3} spacing={1} alignItems="center">
            <Grid item>AAAAAAA</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={7}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 7, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid justify='flex-end' container item xs={8} spacing={1} alignItems="center">
            <Grid item>BBBB</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        
            <Grid item>CCCC</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>DDDD</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>EEEE/E</Grid>
            <Grid item item xs={2}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 4, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>/</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Input 
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 1, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item style={{width:"850px"}}>
        <Grid container item xs={6} spacing={1} alignItems="center">
            <Grid item>FFF/FFF</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={9}>
                <Input 
                    fullWidth="true"
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 21, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item xs={6} spacing={1} alignItems="center">
            <Grid item>GGGG</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={10}>
                <Input 
                    fullWidth="true"
                    inputProps={{maxLength: 21, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container item style={{border:"1px solid red", width:"1000px"}}>
        <Grid container spacing={1} xs={2} alignItems="center">
            <Grid item>HHHH</Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <Input 
                    fullWidth="true"
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: 4, size: 4, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container spacing={1} xs={2} alignItems="center">
            <Grid item>IIII</Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <Input 
                    fullWidth="true"
                    inputProps={{maxLength: 4, size: 4, style: { textTransform: "uppercase" } }} 
                />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply, but I may have badly asked my question ^^ For the 1st point, I'm looking for a way to have the left border of the inputs fields associated to "AAAAAAA", "FFF/FFF" and "HHHH" aligned (you can see on the images that they are not)
I could find a workaround by hardcoding a width of 80px for each grid containing the texts "AAAAAAA", "FFF/FFF" and "HHHH" so that each input field starts at the same position, but this is a dirty solution, i was wondering if a cleaner solution exists.

Comment: And for the second problem, I edited the text of the issue. I updated also the screenshot to make it clearer